# Progress OpenEdge passing a dataset as parameter looses values

Tags: openedge

I am trying to pass a dataset as a parameter to a class, but the dataset keeps loosing it's values.

The idea is to put a customer number in the dataset, pass the dataset to the server and let the server fill the dataset with all the customer information and then pass it back to the client.

## First calling procedure

This is a unittest procedure calling the ServiceInterface in the server.

```
USING OpenEdge.Core.Assert.
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

{USS/Common/Invoice/Include/dsInvoice.i}

DEFINE VARIABLE hProc      AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
RUN USS/Server/Invoice/ServiceInterfaces.p PERSISTENT SET hProc.

TEMP-TABLE ttInvoice:TRACKING-CHANGES = TRUE.
ttInvoice.CustomerNr = CustomerNr.
TEMP-TABLE ttInvoice:TRACKING-CHANGES = FALSE.

RUN UpdateCustomer IN hProc(INPUT CustomerNr, INPUT-OUTPUT DATASET dsInvoice BY-VALUE).

Assert:Equals("MIDDELLANDBAAN 1 B", ttInvoice.DeliveryStreet).

DELETE PROCEDURE hProc.
```

## Service interface on the server

At this moment the dataset still contains all the values. These values are passed to a Business Entity where other values should be added.

```
PROCEDURE UpdateCustomer:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER CustomerNr AS INT.
    DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER DATASET-HANDLE phdsInvoice.          
    USS.Server.Invoice.BusinessEntity.InvoiceEntity:Instance:UpdateCustomer(INPUT CustomerNr, INPUT-OUTPUT DATASET dsInvoice BY-REFERENCE).     
    RETURN.
END PROCEDURE.
```

## Business entity

The Business Entity is a singleton, containing an UpdateCustomer method. 
When the dataset is passed to this method, it is completely empty.

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.
USING USS.Common.Interfaces.IBusinessEntity.
USING USS.Server.Invoice.DataAccess.InvoiceBE-DA.

BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS USS.Server.Invoice.BusinessEntity.InvoiceEntity IMPLEMENTS IBusinessEntity:   
    { USS\Common\Invoice\Include\dsInvoice.i &CLassAccess = "private" }

    DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE InvoiceDA        AS InvoiceBE-DA NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE hDSEventHandlers AS HANDLE       NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTY Instance AS USS.Server.Invoice.BusinessEntity.InvoiceEntity
        GET.
        PRIVATE SET.

    CONSTRUCTOR STATIC InvoiceEntity ():
        USS.Server.Invoice.BusinessEntity.InvoiceEntity:Instance = NEW USS.Server.Invoice.BusinessEntity.InvoiceEntity().
    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC InvoiceEntity ():
        SUPER().
        InvoiceDA = NEW InvoiceBE-DA().
    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    METHOD PUBLIC VOID UpdateCustomer(INPUT pCustomerNr AS INT, INPUT-OUTPUT DATASET dsInvoice ):
        DEF VAR hUpdateCustomerService AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
        RUN USS/Server/Invoice/Services/UpdateCustomer.p PERSISTENT SET hUpdateCustomerService.

        RUN UpdateCustomer IN hUpdateCustomerService (INPUT pCustomerNr, INPUT-OUTPUT DATASET dsInvoice BY-REFERENCE).
        RETURN.
    END METHOD.
END CLASS.
```

I have been working on this for a while now and I hope someone can help me figure this one out.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @ArnovanderEnde Sorry, I pressed enter and the question was posted. I have finished it and added the code.

Comment: Your input parameter is phdsInvoice while you're calling the BE with dsInvoice - these need to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Tim mentioned, you use 2 different datasets in internal procedure `UpdateCustomer` in `ServiceInterfaces.p`.

You can change the `PARAMETER DATASET-HANDLE` to:

```
DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER DATASET FOR dsSelectionList.
```